# Create 2-dimension table reporting average

Tags: sql

In the table Products in the link below, I have 3 columns.

SupplierID, CategryID and Price.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_drop_table

I want to create 3 group of SupplierID and 3 group of CategryID. The rule is listed below.

```
case    when SupplierID<=10 then 'SupplierID_group1'
            when 10<SupplierID and SupplierID<=15 then 'SupplierID_group2'
            when 15<SupplierID then 'SupplierID_group3'
end SupplierID_group 


case    when CategoryID<=3 then 'Category_Mode Low'
        when 3< CategoryID and CategoryID<=6 then 'Category_Mode Mid'
        when 6< CategoryID then 'Category_Mode High'
end Category_Group
```

I want a 3-by-3 table which report the average Price for each combination of SupplierID_group and Category_Group.

My problem is that I am not allowed to create new table or new column in existing table.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

Harry

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `3-by-3`. Could you include your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database is MySQL, this query will give you the results that you want; it works in the w3schools TryMySQL window:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CategoryID<=3 THEN "Category_Mode Low"
            WHEN 3< CategoryID and CategoryID<=6 THEN "Category_Mode Mid"
            WHEN 6< CategoryID THEN "Category_Mode High"
       END AS Category_Group,
       AVG(CASE WHEN SupplierID<=10 THEN price end) AS SupplierID_group1,
       AVG(CASE WHEN 10<SupplierID and SupplierID<=15 THEN price END) AS SupplierID_group2,
       AVG(CASE WHEN 15<SupplierID THEN price END) AS SupplierID_group3
FROM Products
GROUP BY Category_Group
```

If you're running more standard SQL, you'll need to repeat the `Category_Group` expression in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CategoryID<=3 THEN "Category_Mode Low"
            WHEN 3< CategoryID and CategoryID<=6 THEN "Category_Mode Mid"
            WHEN 6< CategoryID THEN "Category_Mode High"
       END AS Category_Group,
       AVG(CASE WHEN SupplierID<=10 THEN price end) AS SupplierID_group1,
       AVG(CASE WHEN 10<SupplierID and SupplierID<=15 THEN price END) AS SupplierID_group2,
       AVG(CASE WHEN 15<SupplierID THEN price END) AS SupplierID_group3
FROM Products
GROUP BY CASE WHEN CategoryID<=3 THEN "Category_Mode Low"
            WHEN 3< CategoryID and CategoryID<=6 THEN "Category_Mode Mid"
            WHEN 6< CategoryID THEN "Category_Mode High"
       END
```

Output for the sample `Products` table:

```
Category_Group      SupplierID_group1   SupplierID_group2   SupplierID_group3
Category_Mode High  27.1667             36                  19.5556
Category_Mode Low   22.3889             22                  39.1429
Category_Mode Mid   37.5                37.25               25.7778
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff6f95/2)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an extra table to preprocess the results. You can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) or a plain table expression.

Here I used the latter:

```
select 
  category_group,
  avg(g1) as 'SupplierID_group1', 
  avg(g2) as 'SupplierID_group2', 
  avg(g3) as 'SupplierID_group3'
from (
  select 
    case when SupplierID<=10 then price else 0 end as g1,
    case when 10<SupplierID and SupplierID<=15 then price else 0 end as g2,
    case when 15<SupplierID then price  else 0 end as g3,
    case when CategoryID<=3 then 'Category_Mode Low'
         when 3< CategoryID and CategoryID<=6 then 'Category_Mode Mid'
         else 'Category_Mode High'
    end category_group
  from products
) x
group by category_group
```

Result:

```
category_group      SupplierID_group1  SupplierID_group2  SupplierID_group3
------------------  -----------------  -----------------  -----------------
Category_Mode High  9.5882             4.2353             10.3529
Category_Mode Low   10.8919            2.973              14.8108
Category_Mode Mid   9.7826             12.9565            10.087
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b6ddf/11).

Comment: I like this approach but the number turns out to be incorrect.

Comment: @Harry Please point out the incorrect number. See the fiddle for details. You can't just say "it's incorrect".